# Fail to download static files from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Our website is hosted on Google App Engine: https://www.boutir.com/

Without any code/dns/config changes today, the static files like .js/.css suddenly fail to load. The network inspector shows that the file is pending forever. Occasionally though the files would load successfully. How do we solve the issue?

It is interesting to note that if we use the PROJECT_ID.appspot.com domain, there would be no such issues.

Our `app.yaml` looks something like this:

```yaml
runtime: python27

handlers:
-  url: /js
   static_dir: pages/js
   secure: always
```

Comment: Can you try to add  `upload: pages/*` in your configuration?

Comment: We are not confident enough now to try uploading a version as some of our other important pages are still working thanks to the edge cache and we are trying not to invalidate the cache... In our other project (staging) we have the exact same config and code but there are no issues there

Comment: Similar issue reported in the past was observed to be related to the DNS configuration of the Custom Domain. Particularly since you confirm that the Static Contents are being served as expected with the appspot domain. 

With that being said, there was an internal GCP issue reported earlier suggesting that requests for App Engine endpoints that serve static content may be failing with Customers seeing ”204 No Response” with 0 bytes data, or request hangs indefinitely. 

I have information that this issue is now resolved, however. Is this something still ongoing with your setup?

Comment: Yes, we also heard about the issue you mentioned and its resolution from Google, and our issue has been gone since then. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to know that the issue is now resolved. I will post my comment as an answer, should the same have affected other members of the Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue reported in the past was observed to be related to the DNS configuration of the Custom Domain. Particularly since you confirm that the Static Contents are being served as expected with the appspot domain.

With that being said, there was an internal GCP issue reported earlier suggesting that requests for App Engine endpoints that serve static content may be failing with Customers seeing ”204 No Response” with 0 bytes data, or request hangs indefinitely. I have information that this issue is now resolved, however.